# Problems with ticks and death of mobile agents in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a question that I don't know how to resolve. I have code that exports the following information to a .csv file:

1. the turtle's identity
2. the x coordinate of the patch that the turtle is in
3. the y coordinate of the patch the turtle is in
4. the tick number

However, if I have a line of code that the bee dies when it reaches a certain amount of resource (for example when it reaches an amount > = a 2 resource the turtle dies. To simplify the code I put here that upon reaching the tick >=2 the turtle dies). The issue is that at tick 2 the turtle dies and the pxcor and pycor value of the last tick (tick 2) is not exported. So, just like when inspecting the turtle, the turtle dies and we don't see the last updated tick information.

Does anyone know how I can get this information?

If I haven't been able to express myself properly. I can rewrite my question or try to rewrite the simplified code.

Thanks in advance

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  resize-world 0 3 0 3
  ask patches [ sprout 1 [ setup-turtles ] ]
  let pcolors [ ]
  set pcolors [ 1 10 ]
  ask patches [ set pcolor item (random 2) pcolors ]
end

to setup-turtles
  set size 0.5
  pen-down
end

to go
  move
  output
  tick
end


to move
  ask turtles [
    rt random 360
    fd 1
    if ticks >= 2 [ die ]
  ]
end

to output
  file-open "test.csv"
  foreach sort turtles
  [
    t ->
    ask t
    [
     file-print ( word self  " , "  pxcor " , " pycor " , " ticks )
    ]
  ]
  file-print ""  ;; blank line
  file-close
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question was already included [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050893/how-to-extract-the-path-taken-by-each-turtle-in-the-world-and-save-it-in-a-csv/68052071#68052071) you previously received.

You have to arrange commands in a way that asks turtles to execute `output` before `die`.

For example

```
if ticks >= 2 [output die]
```

Or

```
to go
  move
  tick
end

to move
  ask turtles [
    rt random 360
    fd 1
    output
    it ticks >= 2 [die]
  ]
end
```

Or any other arrangement where you ask your turtles to do things before you kill them, because they cannot do things once they are dead.