# Is it possible to update the agent properties in the interface after its deat in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

Hello I have the following difficulty:

Model description: agents move around the environment collecting resources. Upon reaching the maximum resource value, the agent dies.

Issue: The exported data about the resource collected by each agent is with the right values, but inspecting the agent through the ui, the values are not updated in the last iteration of the agent (it dies).

Question: Is there any way to update the agent properties in the interface after its death?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is relevant to understand why you want to do this.

Normally, a model is built to export its data - via BehaviorSpace or other means that are relevant to your project. While it is useful, during the development of the model, to check what is going on through the Interface (including inspecting agents), I wonder what is the need that makes you want to change your code in order to inspect an agent in the Interface during one more tick (the tick in which the agent dies).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050893/how-to-extract-the-path-taken-by-each-turtle-in-the-world-and-save-it-in-a-csv/68052071#68052071) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68121356/problems-with-ticks-and-death-of-mobile-agents-in-netlogo/68123158#68123158) you received answers to some previous questions of yours, generally regarding how to make sure that your code works smoothly with agents having to export data and dying.
Therefore, I assume your model is now able to correctly export the data it needs from agents. This means that one option for you would be to simply read the file where that data was exported.

If you really want to add code in order to read one extra tick of data via the Interface, then you have to consider that no, once an agent dies its information is gone (apart from the information that the agent exported to a file, which is your case).
This means that you have three options.

1. **Ask agents to save that information within NetLogo (i.e. apart from the export they already perform)**. This sounds very impractical: you would have to declare variables in advance to store this information... do you know how many agents die at every tick in your model? Plus, this seems a very unnecessary structure to just read one piece of data from the Interface. Let's surely discard this option.
2. **Ask agents to print that information**. Imagine that you wanted to know the `xcor` of turtles, instead of just letting them `die` you would do:

```
to leave-simulation
  show xcor
  die
end
```

3. **Ask agents to survive enough for you to inspect them during their last tick**. In this case, you will simply have to change place to the `die` procedure. For example, if the initial code has this type of structure...

```
turtles-own [
  resources
]

to setup
  ...
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    collect-resources
    if (resources > X) [die]
  ]
end

to collect-resources
  ...
end
```

... you could do instead:

```
turtles-own [
  resources
]

to setup
  ...
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if (resources > X) [die]
    collect-resources
  ]
end

to collect-resources
  ...
end
```

So simply switching the order of the `die` and `collect-resources` procedures. This way, agents will not die during the tick in which they reached the maximum resource value; instead, they will die at the beginning of the following tick, which will give you the time to inspect them when they have reached the maximum resource value.

You could also add

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    if (resources > X) [die]
    collect-resources
    if (resources > X) [set color red]   ; Or any other color that would distinguish these specific turtles.
  ]
end
```

so that it becomes clear from the Interface which exactly are the agents that are going to die in the following tick (without the need for you to run a query in the Command Center, such as `ask turtles with [resources > X] [print self]`).

However, with option 3 above, I think this all goes back to the foundational concept contained in both of the replies I alredy mentioned ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050893/how-to-extract-the-path-taken-by-each-turtle-in-the-world-and-save-it-in-a-csv/68052071#68052071) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68121356/problems-with-ticks-and-death-of-mobile-agents-in-netlogo/68123158#68123158)), i.e. do not kill your agents as long as you need them.
I am beginning to wonder whether these questions are becoming all *de-facto* duplicates?

Comment: Matteo, thanks so much for you help and clarification! Seeing your answer, I got the feeling that the question is doubled. Excuse. Because this question I thought I would have to ask for one more tick after the turtle died or ask to hide the turtles or use the "display" command as suggested by colleague Lena. I didn't think I was just making the "mistake" of asking for something after the turtle died. A thousand apologies for the inconvenience of the questions. But, your comment once again helped me to understand the logic of building the model and NetLogo. You know a lot about NetLogo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `display` to force the view to update its values.
For further infos, you can read the [view updates section](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#view-updates) of the Programming Guide.

Comment: Hi Lena,Thanks so much for your answer. But  I didn't understand how to use the siplay command to force interface refresh I looked at the "Life" model as suggested but I didn't understand. Could you suggest me another search source. Thanks

Comment: The best source is always the [netlogo dictionary][1]
I think, you can place the `display` command just after you updated the value and before you let the turtles `die`.
  [1]: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#display